# What are some equivalents of a BF199 transistor?

Tags: receiver, electronics, fm

I'm planning to build an FM radio receiver using the instructions on
http://www.instructables.com/id/Build-your-own-Crude-FM-Radio/

The schematic uses a BF199 transistor which is marked "obsolete" by some component suppliers. What would be a current and widely available equivalent?

I tried to search at my preferred shop, https://www.rs-online.com using the following properties:

- Si NPN RF Transistor
- Vcb max 40V
- hFE min 38
- ft 1100 MHz
- Pc 350 mW

And did not find anything suitable.

The original data sheet is here: https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/BF199-1118776.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a terribly critical application, and there are many transistors that would work. If you have some NPN transistors on hand, try those. It may work anyway, with some reduction in gain. If you'd like to buy new transistors, I'd look for something with a high gain bandwidth product.

Comment: Phil Frost I think you're wront at'll, all transistor're designed for a specific target. Overall, about rf, medical instrumentacion, space application, etc. There's not a simple answer.

Comment: @user14522 It is not the case that *all* transistors are designed for a specific application.

Comment: Yes. That’s why there are “general purpose” transistors

Comment: When I was in high school I did a one-transistor project and I did not have the right transistor at all.  I had an NPN transistor of some total different type.  I used it.  The project (an amplifier) worked.  I thought, let me try some other NPN transistors.  Every NPN transistor I used, every one of them different, worked and I could not tell much of a difference in performance.

Comment: If you want a VHF radio, getting some remaining BF199 from old stock should be viable. In some cases BC546-549 might work, too, but there maximum frequency is much lower than that of BF199. Modern transistors are made for frequencies around 1-8 GHz, so finding a suitable substitute might not be easy.
If the VHF application requires just an amplifier or oscillator (as opposed to some very specific regenerative circuit where you need a BJT, I would try a JFET with a suitable bias resistor in source, e.g. BF245C or BF245B (also long obsolete like BF199) or their equivalents J111, J112

Comment: @JindrichVavruskaOK4RM that sounds like more of an answer than a comment.

Answer (score 2):

**A 2N5109 will work just fine**.

[Datasheet here](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/68/2n5109-16404.pdf).

Comment: You'd get more points if you found one that met (or exceeded) the original specifications, and was in a TO-92 package ;)

Comment: @ScottEarle So are you saying the 2N5109 didn't meet the original specs? I thought that it did. It comes in different packages, but I always buy it in the TO-39 metal package so that I can heatsink it for some of my applications.

Comment: It looks like it meets (or exceeds) the specs, but being a different case style means you can’t just drop a replacement in and not have to worry about which pin is which. Someone with less electronics experience would probably be more worried about getting the pins the wrong way round than whether the Hfe was high enough (for example)

Comment: @ScottEarle Okay then, can you answer the question with a better transistor? :-)

Answer (score 1):

When faced with a question like this, I find it easiest to use the selection "filters" at the web sites of the major distributors. My favorites are [DigiKey](http://digikey.com), [Mouser](http://mouser.com) and [Arrow](http://arrow.com), but there are others and your region may have different suppliers.

Using the Mouser web site, I was able to find six (6) part numbers with $f_t$ between 600MHz and 1200MHz, priced between 80 cents and 5 dollars.

Comment: Check your PIN-OUT because Phillips is different from Motorola and Fairchild it has to be turned backwards to work. Always compare the Data-sheets of different manufacturers and use a semiconductor tester to be sure you got what you ordered especially on Ebay.

Answer (score 0):

The very common BC547 and the 2SC945 will both work in your FM receiver.